# What file does ndk-build look for

Tags: android-ndk, ndk-build

When you use `make` the idea is you have a `Makefile` that you start the building off with. With ndk-build it according to the docs just runs `$GNUMAKE -f <ndk>/build/core/build-local.mk` but like is there a file in my project I need to have or what files is is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, typically it expects to find your project makefile as `jni/Android.mk`, but you have lots of freedom if you need.